# Use the physical location of a row as the primary key in a database

Tags: database

I don’t know much of the behind-the-scene work of a database. But this is what I believe it does. When you use a primary key to retrieve a record. The database go through all the records to find the one with that key. Then retrieve data.

However, In my scenario a record can contain a lot of references to other records. So, everytime I want to access these referenced records I have to first retrieve a list of primary keys, and then use the keys to retrieve the referenced records. The way databases do this is to go through the  records many many times, only to find the ones with those keys, reducing performance, which cannot be compromised in my case.

What I want is a database that makes the primary keys(or whatsoever) to refer to the physical location on disk. This way as soon as I have read the list of keys of the referenced object, I can directly retrieve those object without looking through the whole database.

The "Primary Keys" don’t necessarily need to have any "meanings" - just like the pointers used in most programming languages.

I tried to write my data in binary. But it complicates things too much when it comes to resizing and caching, and I doubt it will be more efficient than the existing databases.

Comment: "*The database go through all the records to find the one with that key*" - no it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic assumption is false:

> When you use a primary key to retrieve a record. The database go through all the records to find the one with that key. Then retrieve data.

Database management systems finds a record through a primary key in a very efficient way with the use of [indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index). Their efficiency is such that each record can be accessed either with a single access or (on the average) little more. So their efficiency is comparable to that of a direct physical pointer, but it offer two great advantages over physical pointers:

1. They make the access to the record independent from the physical position, and this allow moving the record around for managing efficiently the use of memory.
2. They allow the possibility of searching records through a range of values of the attribute on which they are defined.